# Why clear() on one ArrayList is clearing elements in another ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

My desired output should be: 
`[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`

By creating new ArrayList object every time

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i){

      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

      for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j){
        list.add(j);
      }
      result.add(list);
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

I am getting the desired output as
`[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]`

But, not getting same result when trying to use `clear()` (to avoid creating a new object in each iteration) and also the `result Arraylist` gets empty too when invoking `clear()` on `list Arraylist`

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i){
      for(int j = 1; j <= i; ++j){
        list.add(j);
      }
      result.add(list);
      list.clear();
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

I am getting the following output using clear()
`[[], [], [], [], []]` --> Not the output I want

How can I achieve the desired output without creating new object(ArrayList Object) everytime and using clear() or any other concept.

Are `result and list ArrayList` pointing to the same reference or there is some other reason for the incorrect output. Do let me know of something I am not aware of or lacking regarding ArrayList topic.

Comment: "Are result and list ArrayList pointing to the same reference" - yes exactly right.

Comment: You can't achieve the desired output without creating new object(ArrayList Object) everytime. These lists are different so they cannot be represented by the same list.

Comment: Think of it this way.   You are adding the same list to the parent list multiple times and clearing it when done, and now you are surprised when you get a list of empty lists?  If you want multiple lists rather than the same list multiple times, you need to create new lists.

Comment: Because it's not "another" `ArrayList`. (The effect you see is known as _aliasing_.)

Comment: "How can I achieve the desired output without creating new object(ArrayList Object) everytime" That is impossible.

Comment: @LouisWasserman maybe, it’s a matter of the right terminology. Indeed, there is no way around creating new objects (with distinct identity), but this task [does not require distinct storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69190211/2711488), which means, we can avoid coping lists or populating new lists multiple times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

You said:

> Are result and list ArrayList pointing to the same reference

Yes.

To add a copy, change this:

```
result.add( list );
```

… to this:

```
result.add( new ArrayList<>( list ) );
```

## Details

You might be thinking that `result.add(list);` is adding the *contents* of `list`. But no, that call passes the *reference* (pointer, memory address) of the `ArrayList` object you named `list`. The contents of `list` are irrelevant to that call. Whether empty or full, the list itself, the container, is what you are passing to `add`.

So you are adding the very same list five times. All the elements of `result` point to the very same single list. If you add to the contained list, all five elements of `result` see that change. If you clear that added `list`, all five elements of `result` see that change, all five elements of `result` point to the same single now-empty list.

To add different [unmodifiable lists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#unmodifiable), call `List.copyOf`.

```
result.add( List.copyOf( list ) );
```

To add different modifiable lists, construct new `ArrayList` objects. Pass an existing list to the constructor of a new list.

```
result.add( new ArrayList<>( list ) );
```

Comment: Also, note that if you ever use `List.subList()` you are not getting a new slice but a view into the original list.    Change the sublist and you change the original.  To prevent that, pass it to the constructors as described in this answer.

Comment: I think, copying a list via `new ArrayList<>( list )`, followed by repopulating `list` from scratch in less efficient than the OP’s first snippet which creates and populates a new list in each iteration. It would be different, if the loop wasn’t using `clear()` but just added one element before copying. But still, even this can be replaced by [an even more efficient variant, not bearing copy operations at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69190211/2711488).

Answer (score 2):

Your change to use the same list, precisely has the consequences you’re seeing. You add the same list to the `result` list multiple times and the last `clear()` invocation causes all elements of the result list to appear as empty.

You can fix this by adding a copy of the list, reflecting the current contents, to the result, but the result is less efficient than the original solution you already had, creating a new list in the loop’s body in each iteration, without the need for an additional copy operation.

When you want lists with different contents, there is no way around creating distinct list objects. But you can avoid having different storage in this specific case:

```java
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) list.add(i);
for(int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) result.add(list.subList(0, j));
System.out.println(result);
```

This creates the largest list first, which will have the actual storage for the `Integer` objects. The `subList` operation used in the second loop create a *view* into this list, not having storage on their own but just different bounds.

This also implies that when you’d modify the original `list` afterwards, this may change the result (when you `set` elements) or make the sublists invalid (when you add or remove elements).

You can avoid this by using immutable lists

```java
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) list.add(i);
list = List.copyOf(list);
for(int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) result.add(list.subList(0, j));
System.out.println(result);
```

This bears only one copy operation into an immutable list (requires Java 10), rather than in every loop iteration. The lists returned by `subList` are immutable too.

Starting with JDK 16, you can even avoid the temporary `ArrayList` and the copy operation when creating the immutable list

```java
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5).boxed().toList();
for(int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) result.add(list.subList(0, j));
System.out.println(result);
```

Though the Stream API may have an initial overhead that won’t be compensated by saving a copy operation of only five elements.

---

A minor improvement applying to all variants would be not to use `subList` for the last element, which has identical contents to the whole list, i.e. instead of

```java
for(int j = 1; j <= 5; j++) result.add(list.subList(0, j));
```

you can use

```java
for(int j = 1; j < 5; j++) result.add(list.subList(0, j));
result.add(list);
```